# Change pthread cancel type of another thread?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, pthreads, cancellation

What I want to accomplish is that a main thread tries a normal deferred cancel first on a worker thread (executing code that is for my purposes a black box), and then if the thread is still running after a timeout (`pthread_timedjoin_np()`), I want to do an asynchronous cancel.  The problem I'm having is that `pthread_setcanceltype()` is only for the calling thread.  Is there some workaround or hack that will let me do this?  I want to avoid using signals as at least under Linux it seems that an asynchronous cancel will still execute C++ destructors of the thread's objects, which is important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some cases, when `pthread_setcanceltype()` must actually do a cancel (see source below). So, this is a reason, why there is no `pthread_setcanceltype_for_thread()`. The actual cancel type is the field in pthread struct, which must be changed atomically.

[ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2/glibc-20090518/nptl/pthread_setcanceltype.c](http://www.google.com/codesearch#xy1xtVWIKOQ/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2%7CXP6Z3zoy3dk/glibc-20090518/nptl/pthread_setcanceltype.c&q=pthread_setcanceltype&exact_package=ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2&type=cs&l=27)

```
__pthread_setcanceltype (type, oldtype)
     int type;
     int *oldtype;
{
  volatile struct pthread *self;

  self = THREAD_SELF;

  int oldval = THREAD_GETMEM (self, cancelhandling);
  while (1)
    {
      int newval = (type == PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS
                    ? oldval | CANCELTYPE_BITMASK
                    : oldval & ~CANCELTYPE_BITMASK);

      /* Store the old value.  */
      if (oldtype != NULL)
        *oldtype = ((oldval & CANCELTYPE_BITMASK)
                    ? PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS : PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED);

      /* Update the cancel handling word.  This has to be done
         atomically since other bits could be modified as well.  */
      int curval = THREAD_ATOMIC_CMPXCHG_VAL (self, cancelhandling, newval,
                                              oldval);
      if (__builtin_expect (curval == oldval, 1))
        {
          if (CANCEL_ENABLED_AND_CANCELED_AND_ASYNCHRONOUS (newval))
            {
              THREAD_SETMEM (self, result, PTHREAD_CANCELED);
              __do_cancel ();  // HERE THE CANCELLING
            }

          break;
        }

      /* Prepare for the next round.  */
      oldval = curval;
    }

  return 0;
}
strong_alias (__pthread_setcanceltype, pthread_setcanceltype)
```

If you have a big need to change canceltype externally, you can hack the library and set the field directly.

PS: for NPTL (current implementation of pthreads in glibc on Linux)
the easiest way to see how to get `struct pthread` from int  pthread_t  is ... pthread_join:

```
 pthread_join (pthread_t threadid, thread_return) 
 { 
     struct pthread *pd = (struct pthread *) threadid;
```

Comment: The problem is that the cancel field is not in pthread_t, which is defined as `typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;`  It's a field of `struct pthread` which is in descr.h

Comment: [oops, I was editing but it timedout] pthread_t is defined as a uint in pthreadtypes.h. The cancel field is in `struct pthread` which is in descr.h. I can't see how I can get get this from a pthread_t.  The code for `pthread_cancel()` you posted uses the THREAD_SELF macro which reads from a register (seemingly since it's faster than normal read from thread-local storage), but this register would be pointing to the specific thread so I can't access it from another one.  Any way I can access the other thread's TLS, or a different workaround?

Comment: Hint 1: memory is the same for both threads. Hint 2: debugger can access all threads structs.

Comment: The easiest way to see how pthread_t is converted to struct pthread is ... pthread_join: "pthread_join (pthread_t threadid, thread_return) { struct pthread *pd = (struct pthread *) threadid;". Get it? %)

Comment: Well that makes things easy. :)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just one thing to add in case someone else ends up trying this: __do_cancel() is a function that is called by the thread being cancelled (it also uses THREAD_SELF), so that should also be changed to set the exiting bit and call the unwind function for the other thread.

Comment: do_cancel can't call unwind of another thread. So, you can't change from another thread cancel type to  PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS if there is an external cancel request waiting. (the __pthread_unwind function uses THREAD_SELF). Also, calling of __pthread_unwind (declared with  `__attribute ((noreturn))` ) can't return to the caller: "  /* NOTREACHED */

  /* We better do not get here.  */
  abort ();"

Comment: CANCEL_ENABLED_AND_CANCELED_AND_ASYNCHRONOUS requires the CANCELED_BITMASK to be set, and pthread_cancel sets it after it has sent SIGCANCEL to the thread. If I do a pthread_cancel while the mode is deferred, then a pthread_timedjoin_np returns an ETIMEDOUT, what can be said about whether CANCELED_BITMASK would be set?

Comment: @DisplayName if you have suceeded in changing the type of another thread could you please tell me how? I am trying to do the same but if I have to do it without modifying the library I couldn't figure out how to get pthread->cancelhanling since pthread struct is from descr.h not pthread.h. So even if have the pointer to the struct I am unable change its attributes(cancelhandling)